# docker nginx-proxy: How to "curl" from one container to another?

Tags: docker, nginx, curl, proxy

I have a set of Docker containers which right now uses a `php-fpm` image to host one app, and an `nginx` container which right now provides access to that one app.  I have a third container which periodically uses `curl` to strobe a URL within that container.  This command right now uses the hostname `nginx`.  *(The image is based on `alpine:latest` ...)*

> `/usr/bin/curl --silent -i http://nginx/secret_url ...`

Now, I want to use `nginx_proxy` to allow me to run more than one application container.  But, now, how will the `curl` commands know how to send the request *via* the `nginx_proxy` to the proper application-container?  How would there be name-resolution?

... or, does it matter?  If `curl` simply issues a request on the internal Docker network (shared by `nginx_proxy`) attempting to connect to "port 80," and it specifies whatever URL it chooses, will the request nonetheless arrive at the proxy, which is then responsible for resolving the virtualhost name ... which I know that it will do ...?  What I'm wondering is *how* the `curl` request is actually going to get to the web-server.  Am I simply confusing myself?

Is it, for example, the case that the `nginx` in the URL cited above could actually be anything?

Answer (score 1):

I wound up specifying the `IPV4_ADDRESS` of the nginx-proxy container *(within the Docker bridged-network),* then specifying this in an `/etc/hosts` file which I uploaded to the `cronjob` container.

It is important that, whereas the `/etc/hosts` in the container-host environment should probably specify `127.0.0.1`, that *will not work* in a container.  The container sees only "its" network, and so from *its* point-of-view `127.0.0.1` would refer literally to the container itself.